# Excel formula - Sum cells until blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Further to my previous question, Im trying to get cell E20 (Total) to work similarly - sum all cells preceeding until the the formula itself (E20), again to avoid any cells being excluded as rows are added. So far i have:

> =SUM(INDEX(E:E,ROW()+1):INDEX($E:$E,ROW() + IFERROR(MATCH(“TOTAL",INDEX(D:D,ROW()+1):$D1004001,0)-1,MATCH(“TOTAL”,INDEX(D:D,ROW()+1):$D1004001,0)-1)))

So far I am simply returning an error message.

I am trying to sum everything in column E until it reaches one cell above the word Total in column D, to avoid a circular reference. Any thoughts?

[Screenshot of workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRiuU.png)

Comment: Create a dynamic named range to identify all the rows with data, up to but not including the blank cell. Then use that defined name as the range in the sum formula.

Comment: If you are "rusty on Excel", then you're asking on the wrong site. This site is for enthusiast programmers. Questions about general software usage belong on Superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

```
E2:
=AGGREGATE(9,6,(OFFSET(F3,0,0,
   AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(F3:F999)/ISBLANK(F3:F999),1)-ROW(F3))))
```

Copy/Paste into `E8` and `E14`. The formula for the Total is pretty simple:

```
E20:
=SUM(E$2:E19)
```

After entered as indicated, these formulas will auto-adjust when you insert or delete rows in between, because they use relative references.

Answer (score 1):

No volatile or array formulas needed:

In E2:

```
=IF(F2="",SUM(INDEX(F:F,ROW()+1):INDEX(F:F,MATCH(1E+99,F:F)))-SUM(INDEX(E:E,ROW()+1):INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,F:F))),"")
```

And copy down the Column.  Then a simple sum formula at the bottom

[image]

Comment: :P. I offer **two Aggregate**s and you come up with something else :/. anyway, the column to sum is `F`, and I couldn't verify your formula?

Comment: @A.S.H I wanted to see if I could do a non volatile non array formula.  I typed the formula without testing.  The edit works and is tested.

Comment: @A.S.H do not know why, see photo.  You need to fill the formula all the way down.  If you only put it in E2 it will total the whole.  It is contingent on the formulas below.

Comment: When I put it first in E2 then copy down all the columns I get zeros. but when I fill only the "empty slots" it works. oh wait, it works now. I wonder why it didn't first. But yeah it needs to fill all the column.

Comment: @A.S.H I can guarantee that I put the formula in E2 and copied it all the way to E14.

Comment: Yes it works, dunno why at first I had to delete the blank slots. Now it works. +1 for it captures automatically the empty slots. I mean the place where to enter the formulas doesn't have to be known a-priori.

Comment: Thanks. The IF formula worked much better as it didnt continue to shows the sum of the remaining values in each cell as it was copied down.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably better ways, but this will work. I In cell E2, `=SUMIF(F1:F7,"<>""""",F1:F7)` and similarly in cell E8, etc. The range intentionally includes blank lines above and below each block of data, to ensure that Excel will adjust for any lines that you insert or delete.
For E20 you can just use the same format, `=SUMIF(E1:E19,"<>""""",E1:E19)`